# How to check zone(south/north) from latitude longitude value google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

how to check which Zone south or north and Seismic Zone information
 from latitude longitude for google map android.

> 1. check given latitude and longitude data belong to which zone (south or north)
> 2. check whether given latitue and longitude data belong to seismic zone(earthquake point)

Comment: Can you explain better? what do you mean for "data belong to which zone"? north of south of what?
And what does it means belong to sismic zone? it's not something in gmaps api, you need some service

Comment: I want check whether my Gps latitude and longitude (or any latitude and longitude) is from which zone from google map its located to south zone or north zone and also check that latitude and longitude is match with earthquake point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment (even if does not explain a lot of what you have and what you need)...

1- Get your GPS position, considering lat/lng are from the "middle of the world" right west of the middle of africa, if Latitude is positive you are in the north emisphere, if latitude is negative you are in the south emisphere. You can use Longitude to check if you are west (negative) or east (positive) of the origin point.

2- If you have an earthquake point, you have to check if the latitude (and then longitude) of your position and of the earthquake points match. Obviously you can't do an "equal" match since it requires to be within the meter of the epicenter, but you can check the rounding values.
For example if latitude is:
46.12345678 you can round it to the fifth decimal and check if match. There are a lot of functions for checking the closeness of points, it depends on what you need.

If it is not what you have asked for, please clarify in the question and explain what you have (data + code)